# Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries', referenced from method com.example.qaod.AChartEngine.<init>

Tags: android, pie-chart

Am developing small application in that i need Pie Chart to display results. So i add External Jar file **AChartEngine** to the project. While running application showing error `Stop Unexpectedly` and in **LogCat** displaying this errors

`Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries', referenced from method com.example.qaod.AChartEngine.<init>`

my piechart code is from this [link](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/03/piechart-using-achartengine.html). Help to solve this ? or tell me a simple example to create **Pie-Chart**.

Comment: how you added AChartEngine  ??

Comment: Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build path -> Libraries Tab -> Add External Jar File. Like this in Eclipse

Comment: put the file in `libs` and Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build path -> Libraries Tab -> Add Jar Filed Do Like this in Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build path -> Libraries Tab -> Add External Jar File. Like this in Eclipse

That is not how you add JAR files to Android projects. Please undo that, then copy the JAR into your `libs/` directory. Having the JAR be in `libs/` adds it to your compile-time build path, plus packages the JAR into the APK file for use at runtime.

Comment: Haa Thanks a lot for your valuable time. Working fine